# Data in $_SESSION does not update when going to another page

Tags: php, session

I am trying to store a value from a form into my session, It works ONLY when i update the same page. but when i try to put onclick="window.location='billing.php'" or action="billing.php" in the form.
it does not update the value stored in the session.

here are my codes.

```
<form method="post" name="order">
            <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="LBC") echo "checked";?>  value="LBC"></td>
                    <td><img src="../paymentoptions/LBC.jpg" alt="LBC" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>The Shipping takes 1-2 days for NCR and 2-3 days for any provincial.<p>
                        <div id='price'> Additional ₱250 </div></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
                    <td><img src="../paymentoptions/Pick-up.jpg" alt="Pick-Up" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>Office hours: 10:00 am to 5:00 pm<p>
                        <div id='price'> Free!! </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <br>
        <center><h1>Payment Method</h1></center>
        <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='centerdown'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio"  name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="BPI") echo "checked";?>  value="BPI"></td>
                    <td><img src="../paymentoptions/BPI.jpg"></td>
                    <td><p>Pay by BPI bank deposit (we need confirmation of payment through email.)<p></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio"  name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
                    <td><img src="../paymentoptions/Pick-up.jpg"></td>
                    <td><p>Pick up. You have 5 days reservation period. You pay for the merchandise upon pick-up<p></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <table>
            <tr><td><input type="button" value="View Shopping Cart" onclick="window.location='shoppingcart.php?'"></td><td><input type="submit" name="order" value="Place Order"><!--<input type="button" value="Confirm Order" onclick="window.location='quotation.php?'">--></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['order'])){
    $_SESSION['carrier'] = $_POST['carrier'];
    $_SESSION['payment'] = $_POST['payment'];
}
?>
    </div>
                <?php echo $_SESSION['carrier']; ?>
                <?php echo $_SESSION['payment']; ?>
```

how do i fix it so the stored data in the session will also be transfered in the next page? my code right now works but does not go to another page. when i go to another page, the value previously stored in the same page also shows the same value even though i changed the value already.

thank you. hope you can help me.

Comment: `session_start();` inside all pages using sessions?

Comment: Update the session vars on the page receiving the post?

Comment: Why not putting `onclick="window.location='shoppingcart.php?'"` in the form action, like `<form action="shoppingcart.php"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes every page has session_start();

Comment: @pc-shooter i used `<input type="submit" name="order" value="Place Order" onclick="window.location='billing.php'"/>` but it does not go to billing.php. it just refreshes the page and updates the session, but when i change the type to button, it goes to the billing page, but does not update the session.

Comment: Just use the forms action attribute to send your form....

Comment: `<form method="post" name="order">` and `isset($_POST['order']` that's most likely why. You shouldn't be assigning a POST variable to form. Plus, it's got the same name for your submit button. `<input type="submit" name="order" value="Place Order">` - remove the one for `<form>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- removed the name in the form, but still the same result. it does not update when i use  action="billing.php" or onclick="window.location='billing.php'"

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- did that too, but still no. I think the problem is in the input type, when i am using input type submit, it updates the session but does not go to the other page, but when i use input type button, it goes to the other page but does not update the session.

Comment: What if you were to use a `<button type="submit">`? Plus, see Robbert's answer below.

Comment: I did both suggestion but same result. is there something wrong with my code for storing the session? @Fred-ii-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61506/discussion-between-user3927531-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our conversation via chat, am submitting as the answer to close the question.

Your first file has

```
if (isset($_POST['order'])){
$_SESSION['carrier'] = $_POST['carrier'];
$_SESSION['payment'] = $_POST['payment'];
}
```

move that to the top of your 2nd file.